# How do I set a centered or stretched background image?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, background-image

I have universal app. In that app I need the background image to be centered or stretched. That way when I rotate the device or switch it the image displays correctly.

Here is my code in `viewDidLoad`:

```objc
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tux.png"]]
```

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't easily make it centered with `backgroundColor`. You may:

- Stretch it before setting the image as `backgroundColor`, see [How to fill background image of an UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077740/how-to-fill-background-image-of-an-uiview).
- Create a customized `UIView` subclass and draw the background image yourself by overriding `drawRect:` method;
- Or add a `UIImageView` to you view as the background. See ["UIView Class Reference: Alternatives to Subclassing"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

  > Image-based backgrounds - For views that display relatively static content, consider using a `UIImageView` object with gesture recognizers instead of subclassing and drawing the image yourself. Alternatively, you can also use a generic `UIView` object and assign your image as the content of the view’s `CALayer` object.

Comment: didn't work with stretch when i rotate iPhone, if u could help me with centered background i will appreciate.