# issue with big image as background of UIView iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

i have two image:

-map.png (1985 x 1162)(about 200kb)

-map@2x.png (3969 x 2324) (about 650kb)

now if load this image in this way:

```
imageMap = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"];

viewMap = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageMap.size.width, imageMap.size.height)];
viewMap.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width/2);
viewMap.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imageMap];

[self.view addSubview:viewMap];
```

the image does not load completely in iPhone4 (but works well in iPhone5) and I do not know why.

But if i put in bundle only

```
map@2x.png
```

and rename it in

```
map.png
```

using the same code, the image is loaded without problems.

what happens? thanks everybody

**EDIT:**

I think the problem comes from setting the background of a `UIView` because if I modify the code like this:

```
imageMap = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"];

viewMap = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageMap.size.width, imageMap.size.height)];
viewMap.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width/2);
//  viewMap.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imageMap];

[self.view addSubview:viewMap];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageMap];
[viewMap addSubview:imageView];
```

you can see the image correctly.

Comment: You don't need the `.png` when using [`+[UIImage imageNamed:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW10) anymore btw.

Comment: Check if @2x image is actually copied to app bundle

Comment: @Vladimir yes there is in bundle! because with iphone5 i see the image! now i suppose that the problem is that is too big for put this image as background of UIView

Comment: try to use it like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8077854

Comment: or…. viewMap.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@“map.png"].CGImage

Answer (score 2):

Your images are probably too big. You say you have

> -map.png (1985 x 1162) (about 200kb)
>
> -map@2x.png (3969 x 2324) (about 650kb)

The size of an image *file* in bytes, however, is hardly representative of its size *in memory*. To the best of my knowledge, loading an image of AxB pixels results in somewhere in the neighborhood of A * B * 4 bytes memory usage. In your case, that's about 23MB for the smaller image and 90MB for the bigger one.

Considering that the iPhone 4 has a whopping 512MB of RAM and the iPhone 5 1GB and that apps are limited in how much of that RAM they are entitled to, you might want to rethink how big you want to make these images.

If you are doing something like a map, tiling would probably work. See [`CATiledLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: thank you! have any direct example of how to use CATiledLayer?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not, but I'm sure there are numerous examples online.

Comment: i'm trying with load .svg in webview, but i have some problem. If you want check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274383/add-uibutton-as-subview-of-uiwebview-and-resize-it-when-zoom  thanks