# Setting Background image to a uiview

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicolor

i am setting my view's background as an image. for that using the following code. But the image seems to be getting stretched. How can i get the original image as it is?

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Comment: What is the resolution for an image ? .It should be either 320*480 or 320 * 568 for 3.5 & 4 inch screen phone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fill background image of an UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077740/how-to-fill-background-image-of-an-uiview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not advisable to set `UIView` background colour (to set an image) like this, instead add an `UIImageView` as subview of `UIView` and then assign image it to it. This will be same look like you've setting a background.

However, here's the solution for this,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Straight from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077740/how-to-fill-background-image-of-an-uiview/8077854#8077854)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Try this code.It worked for me.