# Image not set in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

**I want to set image on view background.** I am using this code.

```
 NSString *userString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:///background/%@",myString];
 NSString *escapedDataString = [userString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSURL *imageUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedDataString];


 UIImage *images=[UIImage imageWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
 self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 self.view.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:images]];
```

But i m getting error

> [UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14629ce0
>   2015-04-28 15:50:02.662 BoomAGift[21865:2587355] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14629ce0'

Comment: Please see my answer you have done small mistake.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a UIImageView?

Comment: try this...http://stackoverflow.com/a/8077854/3411787

Comment: @Varun can you please up vote if my answer helps you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSString *userString =@"http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgba.png";  
NSString *escapedDataString = [userString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *imageUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedDataString];
UIImage *images=[UIImage imageWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:images];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

UIColor *patternColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:images];
UIView  *patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[patternView setBackgroundColor:patternColor];
[self.view addSubview:patternView];`
```

Comment: wait.. i will try it first

Comment: its problem of UIImage.. you will not getting proper image.

Comment: there is tableview on my view. is this effect on seting an image.

Comment: @varun Hey try it ... it will work for view as well as for tableview also. i have edited my answer check it. please inform me after solving your problem.

Comment: image has been coming but they hide my all controller. tableview,button

Comment: @varun no yar i have check it.   i think your doing something wrong. please share your project or zip file of that so i can solve your problem.

Comment: hi .. friend is my answer is wrong.. i am sure it is correct. please tell me the reason of down voting.

Comment: Friend please explain why you have down voted my answer. so that next time i am not doing same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[set-a-background-image-in-your-ios-application](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/set-a-background-image-in-your-ios-application/)
or [how-to-set-background-image-uiview](http://beageek.biz/how-to-set-background-image-uiview/)

and [ios-uiview-background-image](http://www.codeitive.com/0xxqUjeWjP/ios-uiview-background-image.html)

**Objective-c**

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
 [[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
 UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

**Swift**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
UIImage(named:"YourImage")!.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)
var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download asynchronous `UIImage` with GCD.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~fangohr/computing/ImageMagick/pic.png"];
                       NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

                       //This is your completion handler
                       dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                           self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

                       });
                   });
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @varun, let me know if you have any issue