# Unable to set background image for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uibackgroundcolor

I have been trying to add custom background image to my app.
I used the methods introduced here:
[How to fill background image of an UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077740/how-to-fill-background-image-of-an-uiview)

These codes succeeded in both normal UIViewController and UITableViewController, but failed in UICollectionViewController. It is just all black.

As far as I understand, UITableViewController has the similar structure as UICollectionViewController.  I compared the setting for these two controllers and they are all same (in the view section).  How come the code works on one but not on the other one?

Answer (score 10):

The best way to implement this is to implement through code inside your viewDidLoad for the CollectionView

```
    let bgImage = UIImageView();
    bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg4");
    bgImage.contentMode = .ScaleToFill


    self.collectionView?.backgroundView = bgImage
```

Answer (score 4):

It is working on uicollectionview

```
self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "image.png")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine has given me the solution.

The trick is to set collection view background to clear instead of default.
I have set all views to default so I thought it should be the same in collection view.

But how come only in collection view the default background is black while in others the default is clear? It confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

**try this for set background image for UICollectionView Swift 4 or later**

*1. Add This extension in your code out of main class*

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func setEmptyMessage(_ message: String,_ img:UIImage) {

        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.image = img


        let messageLabel = UILabel()
        messageLabel.text = message
        messageLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        messageLabel.textColor = .gray
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()

        let mainView = UIView()
        mainView.addSubview(image)
        mainView.addSubview(messageLabel)

        //Auto Layout
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        image.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.centerYAnchor , constant: -40).isActive = true

        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        self.backgroundView = mainView
    }

    func restoreBackgroundView() {
        self.backgroundView = nil
    }
}
```

*2. How to use*

```
if Data.count == 0 {
  self.collectionView.setEmptyMessage("set the message", UIImage(named: "imageName"))
} else {
  self.collectionView.restoreBackgroundView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're assigning the background color to self.view, try assigning it to self.collectionView.

Comment: Thank you for your response! A friend has given me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a Programmatically UICollectionview in iOS And Set a UICollectionView Background Image


 self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tiger"]]];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work perfectly than the background color.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
    }
```