# How to set background image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to set aground image to my ViewController in swift language.

I am using the following code :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:”bg.png")!)
```

But the app is getting crash.It is showing the error like

> “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value”(Because of the “!”)

Comment: remove "!" symbol or check the nil value to set the backgroundImage

Comment: because Image could not found, its nil and your try to forcely unwrap the nil value.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That error is thrown because the image "bg.png" does not exist. Usually when you import images to the Assets.xcassets folder, the file extension is removed. So try the following:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"bg")!)
```

You will notice that the background will not look as expected, you need to do the following as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077740/how-to-fill-background-image-of-an-uiview):

```
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    UIImage(named: "bg")?.draw(in: self.view.bounds)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

Comment: @drdrdrdr Could you please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995059/how-to-add-images-for-different-screen-size-from-assets-xcassets-in-xcode-8 ?

Answer (score 8):

Try this Swift4:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg.png")
backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for swift3 :

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)

    UIImage(named: "bg").draw(in: self.bounds)

    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```