# Repeat image in view horizontally and vertically

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiimageview

i know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001569/repeat-image-horizontally-and-vertically) question repeat but i cant get sultion

**I have this image**

[image]

**And i want view background like this**

[image]

i have tried all the this

**i also try this**

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: 
                  UIImage(named: "backgroundicon.png")!)
```

**Thank you in advance**

**EDIT :**

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
 UIImage(named: "backgroundicon.png")?.draw(in: self.view.bounds)

 let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628803/how-to-set-background-image-in-swift

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what you need,

```
self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "abcd.png")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero)
```

Thats all buddy :)

Comment: Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 0):

In your edit, I can see your last line

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

Shouldn't it be patternImage: backgroundicon.png

Comment: i have an .png than what can i do?

Comment: What I meant was, that it looks like you haven't changed the image to the image you want to use

Comment: Thank you for you help !