# How to set background image to the view using url in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, view, background-image

Am developing a app using swift 2.2 in my app i need to add a background image to the view which am getting from the url i know how to add to imageview but icant add to view..

Comment: add image to that view as subView, or draw image on background of your UIView : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26311986/3411787

Comment: thats helps to add default image but i need to add image which getting from url

Comment: you could use an async library to download and set image: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher
or
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: any other simple idea

Comment: @rajkumar can you share some piece of code? you tried

Comment: i followed the method of himanshu movadiya who suggest some method

Comment: @rajkumar its moradiya not movadiya brother .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Alamofire.download("https://httpbin.org/image/png").responseData { response in
    if let data = response.result.value {
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage.init(CGImage: image.CGImage!))

    }
}
```

Comment: am getting error as cannot invoke download with an argument list of string am using swift 2.2

Comment: @rajkumar what kind of method you use for download image in your project ? did you update your question with that method

Comment: i just followed your answer..also am having alamofire framework but dont know why thats giving that error

Comment: @rajkumar Did you get a image in at let image = UIImage(data: data)  ?

Comment: @rajkumar now i made changes check it its work fine in my project

Comment: @rajkumar anytime and if problem solve then up vote answer . Happy coding.

Comment: i have upvoted...your thanks

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can't set image to `UIView`. First you need to set image to `ImageView` and add that `ImageView` as addSubView to `UIView`. If you want to load image asynchronously(for better performance), you can use Alamofire's code like below.

```
Alamofire.download("https://httpbin.org/image/png").responseData { response in
   if let data = response.result.value {
      let image = UIImage(data: data)
   }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass in view not image view

Comment: shows me the error of cannot invoke download with an argument list of string

Comment: No way we can set image to UIView. Pass url.absoluteString as an argument to that method

Comment: yes that only am trying it gives error as  
shows me the error of cannot invoke download with an argument list of string....am using swift 2.2 not swift 3

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
 let url = NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.view.layer.contents = image?.CGImage
```