# Image Fit Any Screen

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am making a simple login screen for my app in xCode and want to make sure that it fits any screen

```
import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // will allow me to put a image as my UI background instead of a color
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"BestBackground")!)
}
```

}

This successfully loads the image but i just want to make sure it will load on any screen size from iPhone 6 to iPhone 6 Plus

Comment: at the moment if i move it to an ipad instead of having one picture it prints the same one like 3 times to fill the screen

Comment: You mean like http://stackoverflow.com/a/26311986/2033064 ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the background to a pattern. Just add a `UIImageView` behind all the other views. Set its `contentMode` to `scaleAspectFill` and set its `image` to your `"BestBackground"` image. You can do all of this is the storyboard or in code.