# How to fill background image in subview in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have used scrollview. Over the Scrollview I have a UIView where I can set up my image as a background. But problem is that image height is  not merged with UIView height. It is shown when scrolling bottom. I want add image with whole UIView.
Here is my image screen shot

[image]

Here is my code

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background_image")
backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
self.my_view_2.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at:0)
```

Please Help me
Thanks

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have used .scaleToFill. But it is not working

Comment: @dahiya_boy hello sir, is it .scaleToTit  or .scaleToFill

Comment: Set your image's frame to your uiview's frame

Comment: Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077740/how-to-fill-background-image-of-an-uiview

Comment: @ Ashish Kakkad thanks I am checkhing

Comment: @Suganya Marlin Hello how to set up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Height of your `UIImageView` is same as screen size, if your view is greater than screen size, then white view will remain at bottom.

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

Update frame of `backgroundImage` with scroll's view, as:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: self.my_view_2.bounds)
backgroundImage.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth] // In case if your my_view_2 frames increases
self.my_view_2.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

Comment: I have updated to  UIImageView(frame: self.my_view_2.bounds). But it width is not adjust now

Comment: Is your `my_view_2`'s width is greater than view's width?

Comment: @ Ankit Jayaswa No I have added constraints  with main view width

Comment: @ Ankit Jayaswa that means constraint my_view_2 main view height & width

Comment: Update `autoresizingMask` with `[.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]`. I have updated my answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your viewDidLoad(). May be helps you to solve.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
   automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: my_view_2.bounds)
backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background_image")
backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
self.my_view_2.addSubview(backgroundImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it may help

```
self.my_view_2.layer.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "background_image");
```